# How Do I Put The Password In To Sync The Outlook Account

Tags: lumia-635

I try to connect to the internet and it lets me but I cant get on anything without it saying it cant connect so I need to know how to put the password in my phone so I can fix, sync and update the outlook account.

Comment: Do you want to change the password of your associated outlook account? Is your phone running WP8.1 or Windows10?

Comment: Also, can you confirm the date/time are correct on your phone, any error codes/messages it's giving you, and also that you can browse the web from the phone's browser?